# MarkLogic - Utilize Property Range Index in REST API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

How can we make the out-of-the box search APIs (for example, GET V1/search) utilize property range index? I created a custom REST API (GET v1/resources) and coded cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery to utilize the property range query, but can switch back to non-custom REST APIs (like GET V1/search) and still use property range index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use JSON property range queries in the out-of-the-box REST API.

The [/v1/search](https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/REST/GET/v1/search) endpoint accepts the JSON or XML serializations of a `cts.query` or Search API structured query.

You can see the serialized form of a cts.query by passing it to `xdmp.toJSON()`.

For more information about structured queries in the Search API, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_83393

Hoping that helps,